# Support for HTTPS web server iOS

Tags: ios, web, https, server, gcdwebserver

I have used GCDWebServer for an http server on iOS. However, by the end of the year https will be required. Is there another web server library compatible with https for IOS? I have no idea what is involved with a change like this.

Comment: Note that this requirement is for iOS apps connecting to HTTP servers, not iOS apps running their own servers to be accessed by other machines (unless of course that other machine is an iOS device itself).

Comment: The other problem is that even if you were to run an HTTPS web server from your iOS device, you would have to use a self-signed certificate, and these will be rejected by default by NSURLConnection and friends from other iOS devices that attempt to connect to the server.

Comment: I have a web server on one iPad and multiple iPads connecting to the single iPad. Does this situation apply?

Comment: Yes, seems like it.

Comment: I just wrote to Apple. Will see. Bummer since tons of apps will be affected.

Answer (score 1):

This library supports https -
https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaHTTPServer
Although its old but very reliable. Our company have been using it for over 4 years and currently we are in process of switching to 'https'.

Comment: How about SSL certificate for HTTPS? For now I'm using self signed certificate, will apple rejects the app for using self signed certificate ?